# Define keyDown event for a label

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to define KeyDown event for a label in vb.net . I know that we can use the keyDown event of the main form , but for some reasons i want to define KeyDown event for label .

Thank you

Comment: Have you ever been able to type something into a label?

Comment: Since labels don't have a keydown event, you may have to stick with the main form's (or label's parent) keydown event and just check if the label has focus when a key is pressed

Comment: `Label` [already has](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Label.cs,cd25d7e912f0746e) a `KeyDown` event (it's also in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx)), but it's hidden, presumably because you can't focus a label so it doesn't work.

Comment: _Why_ do you need this? Better to just create your own control instead.